# Stripe pricing table does not display properly on mobile device

Tags: html, stripe-payments, react-stripe

I created a subscription table with Stripe. I then integrated this with the tag stripe-pricing-table. The view fits in desktop mode, but on a mobile device, the bottom column is cut off. I've also tried padding, margins to no avail.

```
export default function CheckoutForm() {
useScript("https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js");

return (
 <div>
  <stripe-pricing-table
    pricing-table-id="sdfsdf"
    publishable-key="sdfeee"
  ></stripe-pricing-table>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Mobile view:

[image]

On Desktop:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you to make your UI scrollable so that your customer can still scroll up the page if the content is larger than the mobile screen.